# How to refresh a page without reload in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am have a page with many entries right now i am taking 2 like this page url

```
http://localhost/DS/abc.php?id=1
```

1-280-12/09/2013-er-0-delete
2-280-12/09/2013-edr-0-delete .....
So when i delete it goes to page with blank id and ofcourse that id is deleted.I want that it should reload or stay on same page with reload to same id.Here id=serial no in column which is 1,2 and 280 is part no. My delete code is

```
<?php
      include_once('db.php');

    if( isset($_GET['del']) )
       {
$id = $_GET['del'];
$sql= "DELETE FROM audi WHERE id='$id'";
$res= mysql_query($sql) or die("Failed".mysql_error());
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=abc.php?id='.$id.''>";

       }   ?>
```

Comment: Delete VIA a Get request is the worst thing you can do! A browser that precaches pages will just wipe out the DB.

Comment: but its working fine 4 me except abov.whats ur solution????

Comment: I don't think you can do what you are looking for explicity server side like you are asking. Try using an Ajax request with javascript. I also highly agree with @epascarello.

Comment: it works fine for you because your browser isn't precaching the pages. You can do it with php, you would just need to do a redirect with php back to the original page, however an ajax request would be a far better solution.

Comment: Yes, you're already attempting to do that yourself, you just have mistakes in your quotes. See the answer by user1615099. did you even try it before saying you already did?

Comment: @user3084297 You have a SERIOUS sql injection AND convert from mysql_* to mysqli or PDO. This will make your life more great.

Comment: yes i did try,looking for which i have not treid

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
      include_once('db.php');

    if( isset($_GET['del']) )
       {
$id = $_GET['del'];
$sql= "DELETE FROM audi WHERE id='$id'";
$res= mysql_query($sql) or die("Failed".mysql_error());

echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=abc.php?id=".$id."'>"; // <- CORRECTION

       }   ?>
```

Comment: Test it by "echo $id" on delete page or use header('location:abc.php?id='.$id)

Comment: @user3084297 i don't see any mention of `echo` in his suggestion. that's literal php code.

Comment: use <?php header('location:abc.php?id='.$id); ?> only ... not echo

Comment: what are u doin man ? copy this only <?php header('location:abc.php?id='.$id); ?> ...

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\wamp\www\DS\delete1.php on line 9

Comment: use header('location:abc.php?id='.$id); only coz you have already placed <?php ?> and you cannot place <?php tag in between the parent one

Comment: its redirecting to blank page

Comment: let me know your email so i can further help u

Comment: nefernandez1@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to achieve this:

Create one html page with javascript like this:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        function deleteEntry(del) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'delete.php',
                data: { del: del},
                success: function(response) {
                    alert('Entry Deleted')
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <button onclick="deleteEntry(5)">Delete Entry</button>
    <!--5 is the del variable-->

</body>
</html>
```

Then create a php file called "delete.php" like this:

```
<?php
  include_once('db.php');

    if( isset($_GET['del']) )
    {
        $id = $_GET['del'];
        $sql= "DELETE FROM audi WHERE id='$id'";
        $res= mysql_query($sql) or die("Failed".mysql_error());
   }   
?>
```

Let me know if this works, cheers!

The physical "delete" button is just for show, you can use the same principle to constantly reload the php file while passing delete ids.